# python stripe is not returning expected result

Tags: python-3.x, django, stripe-payments, python-3.6

In my python code i have a code to get 3 stripe customer list using this code:

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_DftufeqrQlvZHqPdIgGmf9ro00exkHljNF"
stripe.Customer.list(limit=3)
print(stripe)
```

what output i am getting is :

```
<module 'stripe' from '/var/www/html/project/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/__init__.py'>
```

I dont know why i am getting this instead of result can anyone please help me related this ??

Comment: Shouldn't this be something like `result = stripe.Customer.list(limit=3)` and then print(result)?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the list to a variable you can print them. `stripe` is the Python client library object.

```
customers = stripe.Customer.list(limit=3)
print(customers)
```

or with no variable:

```
print(stripe.Customer.list(limit=3))
```